# Одинаковое время воспроизведения анимаций в blender

Tags: blender, mixamo

Проблема в следующем я перенес из mixamo анимации в blender. В анимации idle  250 кадров. В анимации run 17 кадров. Из-за этого анимация бега прекращается, но если я ставлю в настройках 17 кадров то анимация idle получается как бы обрезанной. Как мне быть у меня не выходит анимации по времени разделить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]